# problem with getExpoPushTokenAsync with error "Couldn't get GCM token for device"

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-messaging, expo, react-native-fcm

I have searched a lot about this error But I'm keep getting "Couldn't get GCM token for device"

> 1- I've tried expo start and then run the project 
>   2- I've logged in to my expo account and I can see my name in expo dev tools but no difference
>    3- I've added FCM to my project and send FCM's service key to expo servers
>   4- I've deleted my node module folder and run npm  install 
>   5- I'm running on a Android device

Thank you in advance

Packages.js :

```
  {
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "expo start",
      "android": "expo start --android",
      "ios": "expo start --ios",
      "eject": "expo eject"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "expo": "^32.0.0",
      "react": "16.5.0",
      "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
    },
    "private": true
  }
```

App.js requesting Token code :

```
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
      Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
    );
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;

    // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because
    // iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app
      // install, so this will only ask on iOS
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;

    }

    // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      return;
    }

    // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
    let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    console.log(token);
    this.setState({token })
  }
```

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "hamid",
    "slug": "expo_test3",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "android": {
    "googleServicesFile" :  "./google-services.json",
    "package": "com.yourcompany.hamidtestapp"
  },

    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using an real Android phone?

Comment: @hongdevelop , Yes I'm , I've connected my Android phone to the pc and Actullay I'm not using emulator .

Comment: Just to make sure, did you upload your FCM key via `expo push:android:upload --api-key your-token-here` and also for clarity’s sake, this is a non-ejected project, correct?

Comment: @hongdevelop , Yes I did, I uploaded my key then I tried to get my device Token .Just to make sure, Have you seen my App.js codes?Nothing wrong with the code,Correct ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code?

```js
export async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync(token) {

  const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
    Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
  );
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;

  // Only ask if permissions have not already been determined, for iOS.
  if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    finalStatus = status;
  }

  // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    return;
  }

  // Get the push token that uniquely identifies this device
  let expoToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

  return expoToken

}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work ether.Should I make standAlone application first and then try?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem in that area. If you can try it, please contact me.